# Problems understanding the CURL -X POST command

Tags: curl, appdynamics

I'm trying to create a user using Appdynamics' Configuration API

I'm trying to use this curl command but am not sure what the parameters after --user are.

```
curl -X POST --user user1@customer1:secret http://<controller host_ip>/<other segments>
```

This is AppDynamics specific, a better understanding of tenancy or which my users are, or where i can create users would be helpful.
Also should I be using the pem key to communicate with my controller host.

Here's the link to the Documentation page i'm referring to;
https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO44/Configuration+API#ConfigurationAPI-CreateandModifyAppDynamicsUsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

curl's `--user` command line option sets up HTTP authentication for the request (`username:password`).

In the case of AppDynamics' Configuration API (which is a subset of their Controller API), `user1@customer1:secret` are your account credentials in the format documented [here](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO44/Using+the+Controller+APIs#UsingtheControllerAPIs-Authentication):

- `customer1` is the AppDynamics tenant account name
- `user1` is a user in that account
- `secret` is the password